# How to display tamil fonts in JTable to generated HTML File

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts, jtable

I am using Bamini font to display tamil fonts in JTable. It works fine and display tamil font. But when i click Print button it should generate HTML Formatted output. But if i am using,

```
   StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
   out.append("<html><body>");
    out.append(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0));
    out.append("காஷ்மீரில்");
    out.append("</body></html>");

    try {
        Writer out1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("F:/hello.html"), "UTF-8"));
        out1.write(out.toString());
        out1.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(tabletest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

means it just display the some unwanted junk characters not tamil characters. How can i do this? Output of my HTML File is,

[image]

Here காஷ்மீரில் is copied from another website. it show me Junk characters. Content of JTable display its actual english character not converted character.

Comment: You didn't set the charset of the page. No DOCTYPE, no head tag, no meta tag?

Comment: @Raptor yeah you are correct. When i am inserting <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> this into my HTML file it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic structure of a modern HTML file is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Some contents
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore, your codes should be corrected as:

```
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
out.append("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><title>Some Title</title></head><body>");
out.append(jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0));
out.append("காஷ்மீரில்");
out.append("</body></html>");
```

Comment: Either the `"` before/after `utf-8` need to be escaped, *or* use `'` instead.

Comment: Yes, typo. Now corrected. Just copy & paste too fast